# Trying to do self processing form, getting error

Tags: php

I can't quite figure out how to format the string "" so that it doesn't cause an error.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

Please register:

<?php if (!isset($_POST['username']) && !isset($_POST['password'])) {

echo "<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">";

echo "Username: <input type="text" name="username">";
echo "Email: <input type="text" name="email">";
echo "Password: <input type="password" name="password"></br>";

echo "<input type="submit" value="Register">";

echo "</form>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems:

```
echo "<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">";
```

should be

```
echo "<form method="POST">";
```

because when no action is specified, the form submits to the current page. If you still wanted to specify the action, it'd be like this:

```
echo '<form action="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'" method="POST">';
```

Also

```
echo "Username: <input type="text" name="username">";
```

should be

```
echo 'Username: <input type="text" name="username">';
```

because the string you were trying to echo has double quotes.

Comment: Can you explain why you would ever want to use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] then?

Comment: I can't really think of a practical reason. Someone else who reads this might know one though.

Answer (score 0):

Either escape those quotes (`\"`) or use single-quotes (`'`) or, probably the best way, rewrite your code, for example something like this:

```
<?php if (!isset($_POST['username']) && !isset($_POST['password'])) : ?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">

Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
Password: <input type="password" name="password"></br>

<input type="submit" value="Register">

</form>
...
<?php endif; ?>
```

And whatever you do - this line is wrong since you have a PHP tag within a PHP block: 
`echo "<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">";`

Comment: I tried to do this but there are more conditional statements further down the code and you cannot use traditional and alternative conditional statements in the same code block? I think...

Comment: Sure you can (it probably won't look nice), just make sure you properly close them. Anyway, you can use traditional ones everywhere, I just like this way more when inserting pure HTML.